# How to get the 30 days back date in java based on given date

Tags: java

I have an input field, where i can select the date from date picker.Based on this selected value i need to get the 30 days back date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is way too vague.

Comment: You can use calendar instance and then use add(-30) on it to get date

Comment: No, do not use `Calendar`. That troublesome old class is part of the legacy classes now supplanted by the java.time classes. `LocalDate.now().minusDays( 30 )`

Answer (score 10):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cale.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
System.out.println("Date = " + cal.getTime());
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Solution: `LocalDate.now().minusDays( 30 )`